# MySQL: Get total in last row of MySql result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example I have a table like this:

```
product | quantity | something
-------------------------------
 abc    |   5      |  2
 xzy    |   5      |  2
 asd    |   10     |  2
```

When I need all record I do like this and get 3 results:

```
select * from tableName
```

But I want get a 4th row for total of quantity(50) and something(6). Is it possible in sql query or I have to loop my result to get total after query execution? I want to do this in query if possible.

Comment: i think you need to run your request again with a `SUM()` statement (see http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
(SELECT product, 
        quantity, 
        something 
 FROM   tablename) 
UNION 
(SELECT "all"          AS product, 
        SUM(quantity)  AS quantity, 
        SUM(something) AS something 
 FROM   tablename)
```

This is working query. It will add a fourth row as desired at the end of your result

Answer (score 28):

You can use rollup to generate totals, but you have to change it to an aggregate function, like this:

```
SELECT product, sum(quantity), sum(something)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY product WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it is the most efficient and shortest

Comment: Works perfectly and it's simple AF

Answer (score 3):

it's not the best way to solve this but should do the trick

```
select product, quantity, something from tableName
union 
select 'sum', sum(quantity), sum(something) from tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
SELECT Product, Quantity, Something 
FROM TABLENAME

UNION

SELECT 'ALL', SUM(Quantity),SUM(Something) 
FROM TABLENAME
```

This would not, however, add a row in your table.  Which is probably not a good idea anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q="select sum(quantity), sum(something) from tableName";
```