# Sum for specific condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

For query:

```
select date, query_type, light_mapped_count, heavy_mapped_count, lightandheavy_mapped_count, total_queries
from search_converted_play
```

I'm getting:

```
| date       | query_type     | light_mapped_count | heavy_mapped_count |
| 2015-01-01 | browse         |                162 |                592 |
| 2015-01-01 | browse_scroll  |                 11 |                 48 |
| 2015-01-02 | browse         |                640 |               3001 |                        253 |
| 2015-01-02 | browse_scroll  |                 75 |                570 |                         49 |
```

Now, I want the sum for all the query type for light_mapped_count and heavy_mapped_count for a specific date, so the output should be:

```
| date       | query_type     | light_mapped_count | heavy_mapped_count |
| 2015-01-01 | browse         |                162 |                592 |
| 2015-01-01 | browse_scroll  |                 11 |                 48 |
| 2015-01-01 | all            |                173 |                640 |
| 2015-01-02 | browse         |                640 |               3001 |                        253 |
| 2015-01-02 | browse_scroll  |                 75 |                570 |                         49 |
| 2015-01-02 | all            |                715 |               3571 |
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Get total in last row of MySql result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232306/mysql-get-total-in-last-row-of-mysql-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using UNION like below:

```
SELECT date, query_type, light_mapped_count, heavy_mapped_count
FROM search_converted_play
UNION
SELECT date, 'all', SUM(light_mapped_count), SUM(heavy_mapped_count)
FROM search_converted_play
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Tried this, but for each date, i'm now getting 2 query types. eg. for 2015-01-01 I'm getting 2 'browse', etc..

Comment: I just used your query above and trusted you were actually getting one row.